# Functional dual question

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it true that $L^1$ is the dual of $(L^{\infty}(\Omega),||\cdot||_p)$ for any $p > 0$, where the p-norm symbol denotes quasinorm for $p <1$, where $\Omega$ has finite measure?

Comment: I suspect it is $\{0\}$ instead of $L_1$.